# Does Wordpress Importer notify imported Users?

Tags: users, import, export

I have exported an XML/WXR from one site with many posts and many users, using the Export tool.

I want to migrate that to another site.

I have begun using the Import tool. Because none of the users yet exist on the destination site, WordPress asks if I'd like to import them.

I need to know - would this step initiate an email being sent out to those users upon import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not. It simply imports them as if they've always been a user.